# Respond from Volley library comes in twice

Tags: rest, android-volley

I am trying to figure out why a response from the Volley library comes in twice (and it is not always the same response that is doubled).

This is the result, a pie chart:

[image]

As we can see the total income and the total spending comes in twice (and if I debug it, it is never 4 GET calls, it is always at least 6 GET calls, although only 4 methods are executed).

Here is my code where I am trying to execute 4 GET requests.

```
public void initialize() {
        getOutputFromDatabase(StaticFields.INCOME);
        getOutputFromDatabase(StaticFields.EXPENSE);
        getOutputFromDatabase(StaticFields.SAVINGS);
        getOutputFromDatabase(StaticFields.FOOD);
}

   private void getOutputFromDatabase(String incomeOrExpenseOrSavingsOrFood) {
        //RequestQueue initialized
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        // REST URL
        String url = null;
        if(incomeOrExpenseOrSavingsOrFood.equals("income")) {
            url = StaticFields.PROTOCOL +
                    sharedPref_IP +
                    StaticFields.COLON +
                    sharedPref_Port +
                    StaticFields.REST_URL_GET_SUM_INCOME;
        } else if (incomeOrExpenseOrSavingsOrFood.equals("expense")) {
            url = StaticFields.PROTOCOL +
                    sharedPref_IP +
                    StaticFields.COLON +
                    sharedPref_Port +
                    StaticFields.REST_URL_GET_SUM_EXPENSE;
        } else if (incomeOrExpenseOrSavingsOrFood.equals("savings")) {
            url = StaticFields.PROTOCOL +
                    sharedPref_IP +
                    StaticFields.COLON +
                    sharedPref_Port +
                    StaticFields.REST_URL_GET_SUM_SAVINGS;
        } else if (incomeOrExpenseOrSavingsOrFood.equals("food")) {
            url = StaticFields.PROTOCOL +
                    sharedPref_IP +
                    StaticFields.COLON +
                    sharedPref_Port +
                    StaticFields.REST_URL_GET_SUM_FOOD;
        }

        //String Request initialized
        StringRequest mStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                    jsonArray.put(obj);

                    JSONObject locs = obj.getJSONObject("incomeexpense");
                    JSONArray recs = locs.getJSONArray("Total income");

                    String repl = recs.getString(0);

                    if(incomeOrExpenseOrSavingsOrFood.equals("income") && repl.equals("null")) {
                        totalIncome.setText("0");
                    } else if(incomeOrExpenseOrSavingsOrFood.equals("income") && !repl.equals("null")){
                        totalIncome.setText(repl);
                        pieChart.addPieSlice(
                                new PieModel(
                                        "Total income",
                                        Float.parseFloat(repl),
                                        Color.parseColor("#99CC00")));
                    } else if(incomeOrExpenseOrSavingsOrFood.equals("expense") && repl.equals("null")) {
                        totalExpense.setText("0");
                    } else if(incomeOrExpenseOrSavingsOrFood.equals("expense") && !repl.equals("null")) {
                        totalExpense.setText(repl);
                        pieChart.addPieSlice(
                                new PieModel(
                                        "Total spending",
                                        Float.parseFloat(repl),
                                        Color.parseColor("#FF4444")));
                    } else if(incomeOrExpenseOrSavingsOrFood.equals("savings") && repl.equals("null")) {
                        totalSavings.setText("0");
                    } else if(incomeOrExpenseOrSavingsOrFood.equals("savings") && !repl.equals("null")) {
                        totalSavings.setText(repl);
                        pieChart.addPieSlice(
                                new PieModel(
                                        "Total savings",
                                        Float.parseFloat(repl),
                                        Color.parseColor("#33B5E5")));
                    } else if(incomeOrExpenseOrSavingsOrFood.equals("food") && repl.equals("null")) {
                        totalFood.setText("0");
                    } else if(incomeOrExpenseOrSavingsOrFood.equals("food") && !repl.equals("null")) {
                        totalFood.setText(repl);
                        pieChart.addPieSlice(
                                new PieModel(
                                        "Food/day",
                                        Float.parseFloat(repl),
                                        Color.parseColor("#FFBB33")));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.i(TAG,"Error :" + error.toString());
            }
        });
        mStringRequest.setShouldCache(false);
        DefaultRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        mStringRequest.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
        mRequestQueue.add(mStringRequest);
        // To animate the pie chart
        pieChart.startAnimation();
    }
```

Maybe someone know what I am doing wrong here?
I tried different things like

- disabling the cache
- setting a policy

but nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

I found my error.
The problem is that I am calling my methods where we can find the REST API calls in onResume again.

I had in my mind that onResume is called when someone comes back to his Activity, but I was wrong.

This is my right onResume now.

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
//        pieChart.clearChart();
        loadSharedPreferences(StaticFields.SP_PORT);
        loadSharedPreferences(StaticFields.SP_INTERNET_ADDRESS);
        loadSharedPreferences(StaticFields.SP_PERSON);
//        getOutputFromDatabase(StaticFields.INCOME);
//        getOutputFromDatabase(StaticFields.EXPENSE);
//        getOutputFromDatabase(StaticFields.SAVINGS);
//        getOutputFromDatabase(StaticFields.FOOD);
        // To animate the pie chart
        pieChart.startAnimation();
        resetEditText();
    }
```